# RecordNotFound in Controller#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, nested-resources

I am attempting to create an edit action in a controller for a nested resource. When I attempt to run the Edit action, I receive the following Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in IngredientsController#edit
Couldn't find Recipe with 'id'=287
```

Below is my controller:

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And my link to the Edit:

```
%= link_to 'Edit Ingredient', edit_recipe_ingredient_path(@recipe, ingredient) %>
```

Any ideas what may be causing this? Please let me know if any other code is needed to give context to the problem. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `edit` action to:

```
def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.find(params[:id])
end
```

It seems to be the only difference with the rest of the methods. Plus, since you are in the `IngredientsController` the `params[:id]` is the `id` of the Ingredient, not of the Recipe.

You don't seem to have a `Recipe` with that `id`, that's why `Recipe.find(params[:id])` throws an error. Otherwise it wouldn't fail but the ingredient would end up in a totally different recipe.